# Generate SWIG JNI for reference pointer

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, swig

I am trying to generate JNI wrappers using SWIG (4.1) for the following C++ code. The `Header.h` looks like this:

```
class Butler
{
public:
    Butler();
    ~Butler();

    void setHoursAvailable(int hours);
    void setGreeting(const std::string& greetings);
    int getHours();
    std::string getGreetings();
};

class ButlerService
{
public:
    ButlerService();
    ~ButlerService();

    Butler*& getButler(const int & index);
    void addButler(Butler *& addMe);
    std::vector<Butler*> getAllButlers();
};
```

As you can see, one of the `ButlerService` class method returns a reference to pointer, and one of them takes it in. The SWIG interface looks like this.

```
%include "stl.i"

%nodefaultctor Butler;
%nodefaultdtor Butler;

// Type typemaps for marshalling Butler *&
%typemap(jni) Butler *& "jobject"
%typemap(jtype) Butler *& "Butler"
%typemap(jstype) Butler *& "Butler"

%typemap(javain) Butler *& "$javainput"

%typemap(javaout) Butler *& {
    return $jnicall;
}

%{
#include "Header.h"
%}

%template("ButlerVector") std::vector<Butler*>;

class Butler
{
public:
    Butler();
    Butler(const std::string & message, const int & hours);
    ~Butler();

    void setHoursAvailable(int hours);
    void setGreeting(const std::string & greetings);
    int getHours();
    std::string getGreetings();
};

class ButlerService
{
public:
    ButlerService();
    ~ButlerService();

    Butler*& getButler(const int & index);
    void addButler(Butler *& addMe);
    std::vector<Butler*> getAllButlers();
};
```

ISSUE: Adding a Butler created in JAVA like this:

```
ButlerService newButlerService = new ButlerService();
Butler test = new Butler("Hi ho", 6);
newButlerService.addButler(test );
```

is not created in CPP. And while retrieving, due to memory errors, it crashes. I am suspecting this has to with the way I have defined `%typemap(javain)`. How can I solve this? I could do away with the reference to pointer, but I want to see what will work without doing that.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the motivation for `Butler*&` instead of just `Butler*`?

Comment: @Botje I know it would make life a lot easier, but it will require to do such changes at many places. I am also creating wrapper for a 3rd party library which source is under 'LGPL-2.1 license', modifying which would require additional packaging of the original source code. In order to avoid all that, I would like to use it as it is.

Comment: In that case, consider writing simple wrapper functions that just allocate or receive `Butler*` objects.

Comment: @Botje Yup that works! I just changed the interface file to send/receive `Butler*` and it works. Can you please shed some light as to how it worked? Thanks Botje!

Comment: Uh, that's not supposed to work. References are backed by pointers at the lowest level. You cannot pass in a `Butler*` when the implementation expects a `Butler**`.

Comment: @Botje Hmm that would mean some internal implementation have changed. I see if I generate wrappers using the same function definitions as in the question, using SWIG 1.3.39, it works. I will need to refer to the release notes now to see what they've changed.

Comment: Taking pointers by reference is something you only do if you need to modify the pointer itself. Which makes little sense for an `addButler` call.